# Is it possible to write one table in one command?

Tags: mysql

I was doing some homeworks about SQL, and I wanted to know if I could optimized my time.

Ride-along:

```
select new_num, new_titre, new_texte, new_date,prf_nom, prf_prenom
from t_news_new
join t_compte_cpt using (cpt_pseudo)
join t_profil_prf using (cpt_pseudo)
limit 5;
```

In bold and italics, this is all the column from my table **T_NEWS_NEW** and *prf_nom, prf_prenom* are from another table. Is it to possible to use only one command instead of writing all the column of the table?

I know, we can use (*) to select all the column from a table but here *prf_nom, prf_prenom* are from another table and if I do a join, the (*) will be applied to the table that I joined but I only want *prf_nom, prf_prenom*.

Thank you for your help

Comment: To clarify, you are asking how to only select `prf_nom` and `prf_prenom` and no other columns from the result of the join? Which table do each of those columns belong to?

Comment: Alias each table separately. Now if (let say) the alias for other table is `t2`; you can use `select t2.*`

Comment: I tried `t_news_new.*` and it worked ! Thanks you @MadhurBhaiya , that was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You can write the answer on what you finally did and mark it accepted for closure